# Add value in array if get duplicate value in php

Tags: php

add array element if get duplicate element in php

```
$a=[3.00,3.00,8.00,3.00,13.00]
$b=[0.11,0.45,0.22,0.90,0.44]
```

the result should be:

```
$c=[3.00,8.00,13.00]
$d=[1.46(0.11+0.45+0.90),0.22,0.44]
```

Comment: I'm a little confused on how you got $d.

Comment: What is `1.46` here? Something like weight of every number?

Comment: 1.46=.11+.45+.90 because in $a 3 values are same

Comment: Then why first element of $d is `1.46*1.46`, the others just `0.22` & `0.44` not `0.22*0.22`, `0.44*0.44`?

Comment: a question that foul your mind.

Comment: @SmritimayDebnath Please see my answer, happy to remove or update it if it's not what you want.

Comment: what is `3`, `8` & `13`?. Is all are id of any float value ?

Comment: actually $a or $b is array, which has single value or multiple value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as I don't like having the added `isset` logic, I create an array of the unique keys, then create a start array with 0 values for the sum values.  Then just match the initial array against the unique array and add the value in...

```
$a=[3.00,3.00,8.00,3.00,13.00];
$b=[0.11,0.45,0.22,0.90,0.44];

$c = array_values(array_unique($a));
$d = array_fill(0, count($c), 0);
foreach ( $a as $key => $value )    {
    $d[ array_search($value, $c) ] += $b[$key];
}

print_r($c);
print_r($d);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a loop, like this:

```
$C,D; //That be inizialite like array
for ($i = 0; $i <= count($A); $i++)
    if (array_key_exists($A[$i], $C))
        $D[array_search($A[$i], $C)]+=$B[$i];
    else
        {array_push($C,$A[$i]);
         array_push($D,$B[$i]);
        }
```

I'm not sure that work, but the logic is that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$a = [3.00, 3.00, 8.00, 3.00, 13.00];
$b = [0.11, 0.45, 0.22, 0.90, 0.44];
$c = array();
$d = array();

foreach ($a as $index => $per_a) {
    if (!in_array($per_a, $c)) {
        array_push($c, $per_a);
        array_push($d, $b[$index]);
    }
    else {
        $pos = array_search($b[$index], $d);
        $d[$pos] += $b[$index];
    }
}

print_r($c);
print_r($d);
```